# Change Number format in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

My country uses [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Asian_numbering_system) numbering system so 100000 is One Lakh and not One Hundered Thousand.

Now I'm trying to convert a numeric value to words. Pretty simple using [this](http://www.officetooltips.com/word/tips/price__sum__amount_and_other_numbers_in_words.html) technique. The issue is, it uses a normal western style system and I want the result in the south asian system.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you might take a look here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/enable-south-asian-language-support-for-word-HA001130674.aspx

Comment: I'm reaching here, because I really doubt this feature is available for foreign languages, but if it is, I would assume it would require a foreign version of Word. You might check out these Office Language Packs: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/office-language-interface-pack-lip-downloads-HA001113350.aspx

Comment: this one is even a longer stretch, but you might look into the Translation functionality: http://library.vicu.utoronto.ca/library_services/technology/language_settings.html

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the CardText switch using a variety of fields so that it follows the numbering system you want. The following field code will handle numbers up to 99 lakh correctly, if you want to go higher such as to crore you just need to add an extra level of IF fields. Note that the CardText switch by itself can only handle numbers up to a million anyway.

**Input field code**

**{** QUOTE **{** SET n 1099999 **}**  **{** IF n < 100000 “**{** = n \*cardtext **}**” “**{** = int(n/100000) \* cardtext **}** lakh **{** SET r **{** = MOD(n, 100000) **}** **}****{** IF r = 0 “” “**{** = r \* cardtext **}**” **}**” **}** \* caps \* CharFormat **}**

**Output**

Ten Lakh Ninety-Nine Thousand Nine Hundred Ninety-Nine

I have uploaded a [demo](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4h-y94oB7DOUDVsbjNmSl9UWnM/edit?usp=sharing) document which includes the above field (click the link and then choose File -> Download). You may wish to add this as an autotext entry to make it easier to insert.